# Can you ask questions with "obvious" in-series answers, if you answer it yourself?

Tags: discussion

This probably overlaps heavily with [Can you ask questions even if the answer is easily found elsewhere?](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112/can-you-ask-questions-even-if-the-answer-is-easily-found-elsewhere), but two differences being:

1. The answer lies *within the series* if you pay close attention
2. You answer it yourself.

Example:

**What were the rules of the written round of the Chunin exams?**
Obviously the answer is found in-series, but not everyone would remember it, so the community might still find it useful.

However, you wouldn't want *too* obvious questions (**What is Uzumaki Naruto's first name and last name?**). I think the community would decide if something is useful or not through the usual up/down voting.

(Note I am aware of [naruto](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/naruto) questions hogging the limelight here. I only used it for examples above since it is the most popular tag.)

If the community approves of it, I will go ahead with posting some such questions. My intention is NOT upvote farming (though I don't mind getting some upvotes. ;)).

I get a feeling that most of the time we try to think up the most complicated questions to ask here. If we lower the bar a little (only a little), it might attract some more users.

What do you think?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with posting questions you know the answers to, and answer them yourself.

As a matter of fact, we already have a recruitment model (it's found here on meta), we agreed that we should seed the site with questions from various series, in order to attract users.

However, note that we aim for the so-called experts. We want folks who've seen a lot, read a lot and know a lot. These folks will ask good questions and give great answers.

If we fill out site with (no offense) kids who only ever watched Naruto up to episode 50, the site will look and operate accordingly.

There's nothing wrong with asking and answering your own question, it's even encouraged! But please try to adhere to the recruitment model for now, we haven't even begun phase 2 of it.

Long story short: do it to share your knowledge, not to attract users.

Comment: Just be aware of the issues surrounding **[Asking the First Questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/area-51-asking-the-first-questions/)**.

Comment: Thanks. Also, no offense taken. I picked the example that most people are likely to know about. I will adhere to the recruitment model for now.

Answer (score 0):

Doing Q&A faq style questions is allowed and even desired in SE sites. ([There is this blog post by Jeff Atwood](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)).

> So …
>
> - if you have a question that you already know the answer to
> - if you’d like to document it in public so others (including yourself) can find it later
> - it is OK to ask, and answer, your own question on a relevant Stack Exchange site.
>
>   To be crystal clear, **it is not merely OK to ask and answer your own question, it is *explicitly encouraged*.**[sic]

As long as your question (and answer) is within the guidelines, structured, well phrased and relevant, there is nothing on the difficulty of the question.

Many users ask questions a google search away, and these questions are alright, if they meet the basic criteria.

You can even use SE sites as a flashcards / knowledge base of sorts.

TL;DR: yes.